# How to remove .html from Magento 2catergory url and product URL

Tags: magento2.3

How can I remove .html from Magento 2catergory URL and product URL. I'm getting a Unique constraint violation issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As per Magento Official Guide, you can change like this:

1. On the Admin sidebar, go to `Stores > Settings > Configuration`.
2. In the left panel, expand `Catalog` and choose `Catalog` underneath.
3. Expand  the `Search Engine Optimizations` section and set the options:

- Set Product URL Suffix to **html** or **htm**. Enter the suffix without a
  period, because it is applied automatically.
- Set Category URL Suffix to **html** or **htm**. Enter the suffix without a
  period, because it is applied automatically.
- Set Use Categories Path for Product URLs to your preference.

4. When complete, click  `Save Config`.
5. When prompted, click the Cache Management link in the system message and refresh the invalid cache.

Answer (score 1):

As per the instructions presented in the official documentation http://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/catalog-urls.html#configure-catalog-urls, just go in the admin to ***Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization*** and replicate the below settings (uncheck **'Use system value'** for **Product URL suffix** and **Category URL suffix** and remove the '.html' value from the inputs):

[image]